# How to store the toggle button states (true/false) at run time to a boolean array

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have 5 Toggle buttons in my app,i need to store the states of the toggle button ,that is "true" when a user turns it on,and  false when the user turns it off.I want to store the states in a boolean array in shared preference, the main problem is, i dont know how to store the state of a toggle button at run time in shared preference

Answer (score 1):

Save it with this code:

```
public void saveSettings(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putBoolean(someNameForPreference1, someButton1.isChecked());
    // the same for other buttons
    editor.commit();
}
```

load setting with this code:

```
public static void loadSettings(Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
        someButton1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(someNameForPreference1, false);
// the same for other buttons
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for saving the boo value:

```
SharedPreferences singltonInstance = ctx.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = singltonInstance.edit();
    prefEditor.putBoolean(fieldName, filedData);
    prefEditor.commit();
```

Save each toggle button states with there name as fieldName and the boolean value in filedData.
To get the data back from the SharedPreferences:

```
 singltonInstance.getBoolean(fieldName, defaultValue);
```

where defaultValue is false or true if the field key not exists.